# Compare and display characters if they are in string/array or if they are dont exists

Tags: php, arrays, string, character

I cant wrap it around my head on how to compare a char of a string to an element in a string or an array.

The result I'm looking for goes like this, I want to check the word *concept* for the letter *c*.

At the same time still display the word *concept* and for the first occurrence of *c* make it bold or underline it just to make it stick out.

I feel that I'm on the right track and just need a little guidance.

```
<?php
 $word = "conrad"; 
 $str = array("Concept", "Support", "Design", "Fresh", "Aged","Glad");


  echo $test = implode(" ", $str). '<br />';

 foreach(str_split($word) as $position => $letter) {
   if(stripos($str[$position], $letter) !== false) { 

    echo $letter .' found in <b>'. $str[$position] . '</b>';

    $pos = stripos($str[$position], $letter);

    echo ' posistion '. $pos .'<br>';

    }
   }
   var_dump(str_split($word), $position, $letter, $str[$position], $test);

  ?>
```

If anything is unclear please let me know and ill try and clarify things better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$word = "conrad";
$str = array("Concept", "Support", "Design", "Fresh", "Aged","Glad");

$test = implode(" ", $str)";
echo "{$test}<br />;

foreach(str_split($word) as $position => $letter) {
    if(stripos($str[$position], $letter) !== false) {
        $message = "{$letter} found in ";
        // This is very basic, but gets the job done quickly
        $firstLetterFlag = false;
        foreach(str_split($str[$position]) as $strLetter) {
            if (
                strtolower($strLetter) === strtolower($letter) &&
                $firstLetterFlag === false
            ) {
                $firstLetterFlag = true;
                $strLetter = "<b>{$strLetter}</b>";
            }
            $message .= $strLetter;
        }
        $pos = stripos($str[$position], $letter);
        $message .= " position {$pos}<br>";
        echo $message;
    }
}

var_dump(str_split($word), $position, $letter, $str[$position], $test);
```

You should used a nested `foreach` and interpolate your strings properly. Note the curly braces are not necessary, but more properly denote that a variable is being interpolated.

### Edit

As [Robby Cornelissen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen) pointed out in comments, his method is much faster than mine. I incorrectly said that regexes will almost always slow you down. As he correctly pointed out, this is a generalization. Regex functions such as `preg_replace` are fractionally slower than its counterpart `str_replace`. However more code, as in my answer, will typically run more slowly than less code, as in Robby's. Regardless, we're talking about nanoseconds. It was my error to bring speed, as it's negligible in this situation.

Now, I promised cleaner code. After playing around for a bit, it became quickly apparent that this is not the best use case for a recursive function. However, functional programming is always better than procedural, and as Linus Torvalds said, "If you need more than 3 levels of indentation, you're screwed anyway, and should fix your program."

```
<?php
$word = "conrad";
$str = ["Concept", "Support", "Design", "Fresh", "Aged","Glad"];

$test = implode(" ", $str)";
echo "{$test}<br />;

function findLetter($testWord = "", $wordList = [])
{
    foreach(str_split($testWord) as $position => $letter) {
        if(stripos($wordList[$position], $letter) !== false) {
            echo buildMessage($letter, $wordList[$position]);
        }
    }
}

function buildMessage($letter, $word, $firstLetterFlag = false)
{
    $message = "{$letter} found in ";
    foreach(str_split($word) as $wordLetter) {
        if (
            strtolower($wordLetter) === strtolower($letter) &&
            $firstLetterFlag === false
        ) {
            $firstLetterFlag = false;
            $wordLetter = "<b>{$wordLetter}</b>";
        }
        $message .= $wordLetter;
    }
    $pos = stripos($word, $letter);
    return "{$message} position {$pos}<br>";
}

findLetter($word, $str);
```

Comment: is there a simple way to just select the first instance of the character? so for the first word it has two C's in it. I wouldn't want them both to be bold just the first one.

Comment: Edited. The flag is still very basic, and the whole thing isalso very ugly--too much indentation. If I have time later, I may write a recursive function that would be much more concise.

Comment: I would be more than grateful, this is new to me so the more the better.

Comment: *"[A] regex will almost always slow you down".* All things being equal (concatenated my output into one string, got rid of the extra content in your output, got rid of the `var_dump`), timed over a 1000 executions, my regex version is about 1.6~1.8 times faster than yours. It's better to deal in facts than in generalizations.

Comment: Can't argue with hard data. Will remove it. That's simply what I've gathered from others without running any tests on my own. As you said, a generalization not based in empiricism .

Answer (score 2):

I only modified a couple lines.  I used the substr function to get the part before your chosen character, then I insert your character (wrapped with a bold tag), and then I echo out the rest of the string.

```
<?php
$word = "conrad";
$str = array(
    "Concept",
    "Support",
    "Design",
    "Fresh",
    "Aged",
    "Glad"
);
$string = "conrad";
echo $test = implode(" ", $str) . '<br />';

foreach(str_split($word) as $position => $letter)
    {
    if (stripos($str[$position], $letter) !== false)
        {
        $pos = stripos($str[$position], $letter);
        $currentString = $str[$position];
        echo $letter . ' found in ' . substr($currentString, 0, $pos) . "<b>" . $letter . "</b>" .  substr($currentString, $pos + 1) . "<br />";
        echo ' posistion ' . $pos . '<br />';
        }
    }

var_dump(str_split($word) , $position, $letter, $str[$position], $test);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using regular expressions:

```
$word = "conrad"; 
$strs = array("Concept", "Support", "Design", "Fresh", "Aged", "Glad");

foreach($strs as $i=>$str) {
    echo preg_replace('/' . $word{$i} . '/i', '<b>${0}</b>', $str, 1) . "<br>\n";
}
```

Which prints out (with some styling):

```css
b { color: red; }
```

```html
<b>C</b>oncept<br>
Supp<b>o</b>rt<br>
Desig<b>n</b><br>
F<b>r</b>esh<br>
<b>A</b>ged<br>
Gla<b>d</b><br>
```

Comment: I didn't even think of using regex.